# Does 25.1 allow Markdown viewing?

Tags: markdown

With the new 25.1 installed, I'm wondering if there is a better way to view a Markdown inside an Emacs buffer. Would this involve xwidget? Not sure how to enable/install xwidget on my new Emacs 25.1.

Comment: How about installing and using `markdown-mode`?  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MarkdownMode  Alternatively, you can study how that mode utilizes the built-in `outline-mode` and make your own mode or tweak `markdown-mode`.

Comment: We have been able to view markdown rendered HTML in `eww` since emacs 24.4.

Comment: I understand the concern, sometimes we want to check the rendering in a "real" browser, and it would be cool to do it with xwidget. I can only refer to a very easy solution, [flymd](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Markdown#Live_preview_as_you_type).